# Replace input field with read only text in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some jQuery currently set up to remove the input field from view and write the value of the input field as plain text inside a span, however I'm wondering how AngularJS would handle this. The event happens upon submitting a form, that part is already done through ajax as well. It's not just one input, it's all of them on the form so you can see the results of what you just submitted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) and/or ng-hide on each input field and its associated text equivalent.

When you submit the form, toggle some $scope property:

```
<input type="text" ... ng-model='text1' ng-show="editMode">
<span ng-hide="editMode">{{text1}}</span>
```

In your controller, initialize editMode to true.  In your submit function, set it to false.

Comment: This will hide the input, but I still want the value itself displayed as text.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there

Comment: How would you do this for a select/option dropdown?

Comment: Same way.  Put ng-show on the `select`, and an ng-hide `span` after it.  Instead of `text1`, use whatever ng-model variable you specified in the select.

Comment: There we go, I had an array so I had to identify the particular var I wanted out of it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding any of these functions in the html where you call the .js function

```
 <script>
    $(function() {

 $('#fieldName').attr("readonly","readonly");

 });
</script>
```

OR

```
     <script>
    $(function() {

 $('#fieldName').attr("readonly", true);

 });
</script>
```

Where `#fieldName` is the id of the input field.

Comment: This is what I do currently with jQuery, I'm looking to do the same in AngularJS with fields that no longer have ids attached to them. Preferably all inputs at the same time too.

Comment: Try changing '#fieldName' to 'input'